# PHPExcel cell formating doesn't work after export

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a PHP code that will export an array of data to excel. It is working fine but the formatting isn't working on the output. For example, I have an array value of `0:13:00` (it is in 24 hour format). What I want is to format it in excel to `[mm]:ss` so the output should be `13:00` after the export but the value remain as it is while when I look on the cell formatting in excel, the format is already in `[mm]:ss`. I also tried changing the value to 12 hour format (`12:13:00 AM`) but it also remain as it is after export. Can someone help me with this please.
 Here is my code in formatting the cell using PHPExcel.

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getStyle('C3:N199')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[mm]:ss');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you have a string containing `"0:13:00"`? You need to convert it to an MS Excel Serialized timestamp for a number format code like `[mm]:ss` to have any meaning.... use

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A1', 
        PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE('00:13:15')
    );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('[mm]:ss');
```

as described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-date-andor-time-value-in-a-cell) and [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php#L99)

Comment: the cell value becomes `FALSE`

Comment: and some of the cell value remain as it is.

Comment: My apologies, `PHPToExcel()` doesn't work with a straight time value, see edit